# Permutation problem involving counting: need explanation please.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

here is the question:

"Robert has eight guests, two of whom are Jim and John. If the guests will arrive in a random order, what is the probability that John will not arrive right after Jim?"

Ok, here is my reasoning:

a) I will find the probability that John arrives right after Jim (event A), and then do 1 - P(A).

b) There are 8! combinations in total, therefore 8! is the denominator.

c) Let John and Jim be a single unit, . x . x . x . x . x . x . there are spots to order them (.) amongst the other 6 guests (x), therefore 7!

d) However, the unit includes the combination that John is placed before and after Jim. Nonetheless, because I only want John being placed after Jim, I will divide 7! by 2.

Conclusion P(A') = 1 - (7!/2)/8!

As you can guess, this is not the solution. The correct answer is 1 - 7!/8! .
My question is, what is the issue in my reasoning? I can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to write $1-7!/8!$ as the correct answer at the bottom of your posted question?

Comment: yes, let me change that. Thanks.

Comment: I think the issue is with your point d): you've essentially named a "unit" as "John-Jim" (where you're already considering their order). By dividing by 2 in part (d), you're essentially accounting for this ordering twice over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that Jim followed by John is a unit, then you do not need to divide by $2$ at step (d).

If you mean that John and Jim in either order are a unit, then you need to multiply by $2$ at step (c), then keep step (d) as you have it.

Comment: Ok, thank you everyone for your help.